# Get current directory name assembly 8086 tasm

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I don't know why function 47h returns an ASCIZ in buffer. How can I get the name of the current directory? Please help me, my code is below.

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
numed db "Directory name: $"
msge db "Error!$" ;error if jc is set
buffer db 200 dup("$") ;buffer for directory name
data ends
code segment
start:
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax


mov dl,0 ;default drive
mov si,offset buffer ;si = buffer
mov ah,47h
int 21h
jc errorr
jmp final
errorr:
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset msge ;error message
    int 21h
final:  
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset buffer;print directory name
int 21h
mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems here in DOSBOX 0.74
If I put your program `PAULC.EXE` in my directory `C:\ASM` which has a subdirectory `EXEMPLES` and then execute these commands from the DOSBOX prompt, I get the correct response:

```
mount d c:\asm
cd exemples
..\paulc.exe
```

The screen now displays:

```
EXEMPLES
```

If now I return from this subdirectory and run your program again:

```
cd..
paulc.exe
```

I get an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

My MS-DOS reference says of Int 21h function 47h:

> If the directory is the root directory, the string returned is `nul`
>   (first byte 0).

Also, be aware that int 21h function 09h requires a `$` terminated string.

Comment: So what are you expecting the current directory to be? Have you set it?

Comment: i want to print on the screen the name of directory where i work.ex:i work in d:/assembleyFolder/exemple/ -> on the screen must be "Directory name:example"

Comment: Are you running from console or IDE? Has the current directory been set?

Comment: I work in dosBox console.I don't set anything,
the only thing I've done is the above code.

Comment: If you haven't set the current directory, then it remains the root directory, as reported by func 47h. Can you set a current directory in DOSBOX? I don't use it. Is there a command line where you can enter `CD /assembleyFolder/exemple/`?

Comment: the execution : d:/assembleyFolder/exemple/ >> tasm /zi ex   ,d:/assembleyFolder/exemple/ >> tlink /v ex  , d:/assembleyFolder/exemple/>> td ex

Comment: buffer don't change with the name of directory,byte 0 of buffer is change to NULL

Comment: It is not clear whether you actually did a `CD xxx`. Remember too that you asked MS-DOS for the *default drive*. If you want drive D: specifically you need `mov dl,4` and you also need to actually change the directory. As you are issuing assembly commands with the full pathname, I suspect you have not changed the drive and/or directory.

Comment: i don't understant very well what is "default drive".I worked in d:/assembleyFolder/exemple/>> .In the final of program i want to see on the screen the message "Directory name : example".I move in dl, 4 but same thing,buffer[0] is 0 .